# Ehternet takes some time to connect after boot

Tags: linux, windows, networking, home-networking

This has been going for years now, but it's more of an annoying thing than an actual problem, so I lived with it for a long time.

Whenever the PC boots, wakes up or if I even disable and re-enable the network adapter, the PC will take about a minute to establish the internet connection. I've seen several people with the same problem (even worse than mine in respect of time) but no solution ever worked for me.

Here is what I know so far:

- This is not a software/driver issue. Since I have this problem for a
  while I've formated the PC multiple times. Doesn't matter if the PC
  is in safe mode or not, if the drivers are the generic windows driver
  or the specialized mobo driver.
- This is not a OS problem. I have both
  Linux and Windows in dual boot and both have the same issue.
- This is
  not a DHCP problem. Doesn't matter if it's static IP or DHCP, the
  time for the connection to establish is pretty much the same
  regardless.
- This is not a network problem. I have several other
  computers and devices in the same home network and this computer is
  the only one that this happens.
- I've changed where the computer is
  located multiple times as well, so it's not a specific cable or
  router port as well.
- Also, this problem started months after I got the PC in 2017. So it initially worked fine for more than six months. Never got fixed since.

Given all that I was convinced that it was a hardware issue. But since it's isn't that big of a problem I never bother trying to solve it until today. Today I finally got a PCIe network card. To my surprise, after installing it and booting the PC the problem is still there. So it doesn't appear to be a network adapter problem either. (I've already restarted the computer multiple times thinking it could be some kind of initial setup thing but it is still happening, on both OS.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: It could be a power management issue on your NIC. In Control Panel, go to the Internet and Network section, then in Network and Sharing, choose Change device settings in the left pane, right-click on your Ethernet connection, go to Properties, and click on Configure. In the new window, go to the Power management tab and make sure both options are unchecked. In the Advanced tab, check the status of Green Ethernet (disable it), Jumbo frame (ditto) and Power saving mode (ditto). Restart your PC and check if you still get the same long delay before connectivity is restored.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had no Green Ethernet or Power saving mode options in the Advanced tab, but I disabled everything else you suggested but it didn't do it for me. I tried doing it in the regular mobo ethernet adapter as well and testing it but no luck either.

Comment: While you're in your NIC properties (same path as I indicated), do you see any other options that are enabled and that might cause those issues, such as Interrupt moderation disabled (should be enabled), Receive side scaling (should be enabled), Speed & duplex (should be on auto)?

Comment: I couldn't find any option that seems related. Interrupt moderation is already enabled and I don't have receive side scaling. I tried to disable wake on lan related fields just in case but still no luck. Do you think it could be a BIOS related? I remember around the same time the issue started, I changed some bios settings related to wake on lan to try to solve another issue where the PC would seemly randomly wake up while sleeping. I don't think it has tho because some time after that, I updated my BIOS and I'm almost sure that all options were back to default. I will double-check anyway

Comment: I just checked. The BIOS settings I changed had nothing to do with it.

Comment: I suppose you've already ruled out a faulty Ethernet cable and/or dusty Ethernet port, on both ends? Maybe try a different port on the router?

Comment: Yeah, I double-checked anyway but nothing. I had multiple routers and this PC was in multiple different locations throughout the existence of this issue.

Comment: Could be a loose contact in the NIC itself, then. When you connect via WiFi, do you get instant connectivity, or is there a delay, same as in Ethernet?

Comment: It's a desktop so there is no WiFi card. I initially thought it was a hardware problem too that's why I got a separate pcie Ethernet adapter, but it also had the same issue. So either I'm very unlucky I and got an adapter with the exact same issue or the problem is somewhere else. At this point I have no clue what it could be

Comment: If both present the same problem, it's most likely a software issue, one way or another. You can try a full network stack reset in (admin) command line: "ipconfig /release" (enter), then "ipconfig /flushdns", "ipconfig /renew", "netsh int ip reset" and "netsh winsock reset". Ignore the prompt to restart until the last command has been executed without an error message. Last resort: in Device Manager, right-click on your NIC, then "uninstall", choose to uninstall the driver if offered to, and restart, but first, do a software reset of your whole network stack with the commands I suggested.